# std::vector memory allocation issue

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, stl, stdvector

I have a problem when trying to delete a vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<float*> *v;

v = new std::vector<float*>;
v->assign(2, new float[2]);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    delete[] v->at(i);
}
delete v;
```

I'm deleting each element from the whole vector, but I still get an assert. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What assert are you getting?

Comment: This is the assert:                                       Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
v->assign(2, new float[2]);
```

One array of size 2 is allocated, then two pointers to it are stored in the `vector`. When you `delete`, the same pointer is deleted twice.

If you want a multidimensional array, you could try `std::vector< std::array< float, 2 > >`. Doing `new` and `delete` yourself are a code smell. (The same goes for `new vector …`; that is probably not what you really want.)

Comment: the `new vector` is not making a pointer to the `std::vector`?

Comment: It is, but why do you need a pointer to a vector and not just a vector?

Comment: @user1917028: C++ tends to prefer _value semantics_; so you should have a really good reason to create a raw pointer to the vector. Assuming that you really want to do that, you may consider using **smart** pointers like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

THe `v->assign(2, new float[2])` does the same as :

```
float *f = new float[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   v->push_back(f);
```

of course, that's MOST likely not what you want - you probably want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   float *f = new float[2];
   v->push_back(f);
}
```

And using `new` on `vector` is just plain wrong - just use a plain vector. Inside it, put a `vector<float>` - or, if you just want two elements every time, use something like:

```
struct f2 { float a; float b; };
vector<struct f2> v;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, having *raw* **owning** pointers is not a good idea (unless in special cases, like when you are defining some custom high-performance highly-specialized data structure).

In your code - unless you are in special cases - there should be no explicit calls to `new` and `delete`, in modern C++11/14.

Your code sample style seems more like Java and other garbage-collection-based reference-semantics-based languages style. Instead, C++ tends to prefer *value semantics* (e.g. prefer: `MyClass x;` to `MyClass * px = new MyClass();`, and if you really need some *owning* pointer, use *smart pointers* like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`):

```
// Your original code:
//
//   std::vector<float*> *v;
//   v = new std::vector<float*>;
//
// Not good, since:
// 
// 1. You have a std::vector of owning pointers
//    (std::vector<float *>)
//
// 2. You have a raw owning pointer for the containing std::vector itself
//    (v = new std::vector<....>)
//
```

A more modern and correct way of writing your code can be using a `vector` of `vector`s (instead of a `vector` of raw owning pointers `float*`):

```
//
// Vector of vectors (i.e. 2D matrix), allocated on the stack
// Note: no raw owning pointers here.
//
vector<vector<float>> v;
```

Then you can use use `std::vector::push_back()` or some other `std::vector` methods to populate the vector.

---

As a more high-performance and less-overhead alternative for a 2D matrix, you could use a single 1D `std::vector`, and *linearize* the content of the 2D matrix in a *single* 1D *contiguous* vector, of size `Rows * Columns`, e.g.:

```
vector<float> matrix;
matrix.resize( Rows * Columns );
```

And to access element at position `(rowIndex, columnIndex)`, you can use a formula like this (if you store matrix elements row-wise, i.e. *row#1*, *row#2*, ..., *row#N*):

```
indexInVector = columnIndex + rowIndex * Columns;
```

All this can be nicely wrapped in a class template `template <typename T> class Matrix {...};`, with proper methods to read and write matrix elements, and the containing `std::vector<T>` as data member.